# String Encryption/Decryption class that produces different output

Tags: java, encryption

I am running a java string encryption/decryption class that i got from the internet! Here is the class with little modification :

public class EncrypterDecrypter
  {
    Cipher ecipher;
    Cipher dcipher;

```
EncrypterDecrypter(SecretKey key)
{
    try {
        ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
        dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
        ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

    } catch (javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException e) {
    } catch (java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    } catch (java.security.InvalidKeyException e) {
    }
}
```

}

public class EncryptionTester 
  {

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        //Generate a temporary key.
        SecretKey key = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES").generateKey();

        //Create Encrypter/Decrypter class
        EncrypterDecrypter crypto = new EncrypterDecrypter(key);

        //More lines of code to use crypto object
    }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
     } 
}
```

}

My problem is that each time i create an new instance of EncrypterDecrypter class i get differents encrypted string yet the string to encrypt is still the same! My mind tells me that the problem would be the SecretKey object which keeps changing each  time there is a new instance created, i would like to know how i can make the SecretKey object the same for all instances of Encrypter/Decrypter Class if that be the cause of the problem!

Comment: The relevant code to post would be the line that initializes the `EncrypterDecrypter` object. What are you passing for `key`?

Comment: You are right i have modified the code ! I am passing a DES key algorithm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used the `javax.crypto` package, then the encrypt and decryp methods look okay.
Try to generate your key like that:

```
final SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
final SecretKey key = skf.generateSecret(new DESKeySpec(new byte [] {/*The key*/}));
instance.EncrypterDecrypter(key);                     //Initialization of your Cipher objects
String encrypted = instance.encrypt("This is a test");
System.out.println(instance.decrypt(encrypted));      //"This is a test"
```

You should do something in the catches.

Comment: In which package is DESKeySpec ?

Comment: Found it in: javax.crypto.spec

Comment: What could be the key ? Should the key have a limited size ? Thanx

Comment: Last time I had a look at DES was 8 years ago at university :) I believe that the key is 56 bits therefore 7 bytes. I am not expert in this field, so that could be 100% wrong. Anyway, it looks like at least 8 bytes are required by the DESKeySpec and the bytes 8 to [...] do not seem affect the encrypted message.

Answer (score 1):

Generate SecretKey from a byte array..

```
byte raw[] = new byte[]{0x001,0x002,0X002,0X002,0X002,0X002,0X002,0X002,0X002,0X002,0X002,0X002,0X002,0X002,0X002,0X002};
        SecretKeySpec spec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "DES");
```